# How to calculate duration based on ID groups between two specific periods that may have missing dates?

Tags: dataframe, group-by, sas

Let's say I have this example data set

```
data df;
  infile datalines delimiter=','; 
  attrib
  id length = $8
  cycle length = $8
  date length = 8 format = mmddyy10. informat = mmddyy10.
  ;
input ID cycle date;
datalines;
1, 1, 10/01/2021
1, 2, 10/02/2021
1, 3, 11/03/2021
2, 1, 10/01/2021
2, 1, 10/01/2021
2, 2, 11/04/2021
2, 2, 11/04/2021
2, 3, 10/07/2021
3, 1, 10/02/2021
3, 2, 10/03/2021
3, 3,           
;
run;
```

I wish to calculate the duration between cycle 3 and cycle 1 for each of the ID with the desired result is the output of the following code (we can't use `max(date) - min(date)` because there are some missing dates in cycles 3 that's why I am asking the question).

```
data df_duration;
  infile datalines delimiter=','; 
  attrib
  id length = $8
  cycle length = $8
  date length = 8 format = mmddyy10. informat = mmddyy10.
  duration length = $8 
  ;
input ID cycle date duration;
datalines;
1, 1, 10/01/2021, 2
1, 2, 10/02/2021, 2
1, 3, 11/03/2021, 2
2, 1, 10/01/2021, 6
2, 1, 10/01/2021, 6
2, 2, 11/04/2021, 6
2, 2, 11/04/2021, 6
2, 3, 10/07/2021, 6
3, 1, 10/02/2021,  
3, 2, 10/03/2021, 
3, 3,           ,  
;
run;
```

Comment: Why is duration = 2 for ID = 3? How do you know that then date is missing?

Comment: ah sorry it must be empty. will correct it

Comment: No problem. I added an approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data df;
  infile datalines delimiter=','; 
  attrib
  id length = $8
  cycle length = $8
  date length = 8 format = mmddyy10. informat = mmddyy10.
  ;
input ID cycle date;
datalines;
1, 1, 10/01/2021
1, 2, 10/02/2021
1, 3, 10/03/2021
2, 1, 10/01/2021
2, 1, 10/01/2021
2, 2, 10/04/2021
2, 2, 10/04/2021
2, 3, 10/07/2021
3, 1, 10/02/2021
3, 2, 10/03/2021
3, 3,           
;
run;


data want(drop = d1 d3);

   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
      set df;
      by id;
      if cycle = 1 then d1 = date;
      if cycle = 3 then d3 = date;
   end;

   do _N_ = 1 to _N_;
      set df;
      duration = d3 - d1;
      output;
   end;

run;
```

**Result:**

```
id cycle date       duration
1  1     10/01/2021 2
1  2     10/02/2021 2
1  3     10/03/2021 2
2  1     10/01/2021 6
2  1     10/01/2021 6
2  2     10/04/2021 6
2  2     10/04/2021 6
2  3     10/07/2021 6
3  1     10/02/2021 .
3  2     10/03/2021 .
3  3     .          .
```

Comment: Thank u so much. And if instead of cycle = 1 and cycle = 3 I wanted the minimum and the maximum number of the available dates how should I program that ?

Comment: In that case, I would go with an SQL approach. See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL approach to new problem:

```
proc sql;
   create table want as
   select ID
        , cycle
        , date
        , max(date) - min(date) as duration
   from df
   group by ID
   order by ID, cycle
   ;
quit;
```